# Question regarding a domain name ending with "ubuntu"

Tags: canonical, trademark

I'm building a website like OMG!Ubuntu. I know that when using domain names ending with "Ubuntu" I must get consent from Canonical.

How do I get their consent ?

Answer (score 1):

[The Intellectual Property Rights Policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy) as described on Ubuntu.com has the necessary information:

> - You can use the Trademarks, in accordance with Canonical’s brand guidelines, with Canonical’s permission in writing. If you require a Trademark licence, please contact us (as set out below).
> - You will require Canonical’s permission to use: (i) any mark ending with the letters UBUNTU or BUNTU which is sufficiently similar to the Trademarks or any other confusingly similar mark, and (ii) any Trademark in a domain name or URL or for merchandising purposes.

The "Contact Us" section links to http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/contact-us, which is a form:

> Please contact us using the form below if you’d like to request an Ubuntu trademark licence, or have any other trademark enquiry. A member of our trademarks team will be in touch with you shortly.

More options for contacting Canonical are given in their "About" page: http://www.canonical.com/about

Comment: 5 day ago. I have contacted us by this form, and I wasn't got an answer.

Comment: @khanhdev the IP Policy Page also lists an address. Tried writing a letter? And http://www.canonical.com/about lists some more options including a phone number.

Comment: @khanhdev - be patient, they will respond, I had to wait almost a month before canonical granted permission to use their trademarks.

Comment: @FernhillLinuxProject: Thank you for this information.